# WPF bind label content to variable

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have created a simple Tic Tac Toe application to learn WPF. But I can't manage to bind the o_win_counter to my o_win_count label. How to achieve this? Later on I also want to bind the other counter labels to variables.

App.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="FirstApplication.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="ResourceDictionary.xaml" />
</Application.Resources>
```

ResourceDictionary.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF959595" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,0" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="25" />
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="100" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation To="#FFFFFFFF" Storyboard.TargetName="BgBrush"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                                Duration="0:0:0.07" />
                                    <ColorAnimation To="#FFDEDEDE" Storyboard.TargetName="BgBrush"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                                Duration="0:0:0.07" />
                                    <ColorAnimation To="#FF959595" Storyboard.TargetName="BrBrush"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" Duration="0:0:0.07" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation To="#FF00B4E4" Storyboard.TargetName="BgBrush"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                                Duration="0:0:0.07" />
                                    <ColorAnimation To="#FF0083C3" Storyboard.TargetName="BgBrush"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                                Duration="0:0:0.07" />
                                    <ColorAnimation To="#FF4C7B8F" Storyboard.TargetName="BrBrush"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" Duration="0:0:0.07" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation To="#DBEDFD" Storyboard.TargetName="BgBrush"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                                Duration="0:0:0.05" />
                                    <ColorAnimation To="#C4E0FC" Storyboard.TargetName="BgBrush"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                                Duration="0:0:0.05" />
                                    <ColorAnimation To="#4C7B8F" Storyboard.TargetName="BrBrush"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" Duration="0:0:0.05" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation To="#EB2828" Storyboard.TargetName="BgBrush"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                                Duration="0:0:0" />
                                    <ColorAnimation To="#EB2828" Storyboard.TargetName="BgBrush"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                                Duration="0:0:0" />
                                    <ColorAnimation To="#D9D9D9" Storyboard.TargetName="BrBrush"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" Duration="0:0:0" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Border x:Name="Chrome" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <Border.BorderBrush>
                            <SolidColorBrush x:Name="BrBrush" Color="#ACACAC" />
                        </Border.BorderBrush>
                        <Border.Background>
                            <LinearGradientBrush x:Name="BgBrush" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                                <GradientStop Color="#FFF0F0F0" Offset="0" />
                                <GradientStop Color="#FFE5E5E5" Offset="1" />
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Border.Background>
                        <ContentPresenter
                        HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                        Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFFFFF" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ADADAD" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#000000" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace FirstApplication
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
public bool turn = true;
public int turn_count = 0;
private int _o_win_counter;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

public int o_win_counter
{
    get
    {
        return _o_win_counter;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_o_win_counter != value)
        {
            _o_win_counter = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("o_win_counter");
        }
    }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

private void button_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button button = (Button)sender;
    if (turn)
        button.Content = "X";
    else
    {
        button.Content = "O";
    }

    turn = !turn;
    button.IsEnabled = false;
    turn_count++;

    checkForWinner();
}

private void checkForWinner()
{
    bool isWinner = false;

    //horizontal
    if (A.Content == B.Content && (B.Content == C.Content) && (!A.IsEnabled))
        isWinner = true;
    else if (D.Content == E.Content && (D.Content == F.Content) && (!D.IsEnabled))
        isWinner = true;
    else if (G.Content == H.Content && (G.Content == I.Content) && (!G.IsEnabled))
        isWinner = true;

    //vertical
    else if (A.Content == D.Content && (D.Content == G.Content) && (!A.IsEnabled))
        isWinner = true;
    else if (B.Content == E.Content && (B.Content == H.Content) && (!B.IsEnabled))
        isWinner = true;
    else if (C.Content == F.Content && (C.Content == I.Content) && (!C.IsEnabled))
        isWinner = true;

    //diagonal
    else if (A.Content == E.Content && (E.Content == I.Content) && (!A.IsEnabled))
        isWinner = true;
    else if (G.Content == E.Content && (E.Content == C.Content) && (!G.IsEnabled))
        isWinner = true;


    if (isWinner)
    {
        disableButtons();

        String winner = "";
        if (turn)
        {
            winner = "O";
        }
        else
        {
            winner = "X";
            o_win_counter++;
        }

        MessageBox.Show(winner + " Wins!", "Winner");
    }
    else
    {
        if(turn_count==9)
            MessageBox.Show("Draw", "Draw!");


    }
}

private void disableButtons()
{
    try
    {
        foreach (Control control in controlGrid.Children)
        {
            if (control is Button)
            {
                Button button = (Button)control;
                button.IsEnabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
    catch { }
}

private void newButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    turn = true;
    turn_count = 0;

    try
    {
        foreach (Control control in controlGrid.Children)
        {
            if (control is Button)
            {
                Button button = (Button)control;
                button.IsEnabled = true;
                button.Content = "";
            }
        }
    }
    catch { }
}

private void button_enter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Button button = (Button)sender;
    if (button.IsEnabled)
    {
        if (turn)
            button.Content = "X";
        else
            button.Content = "O";
    }
}

private void button_leave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Button button = (Button)sender;
    if (button.IsEnabled)
        button.Content = "";



   } 
  }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="FirstApplication.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="500" Width="525" Name="MyWindow">        

<Grid Margin="0,0,0.4,-19.2" Name="controlGrid">
    <Button x:Name="A" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="117,59,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Height="75" Click="button_click" Background="#FFEBEB33" MouseEnter="button_enter" MouseLeave="button_leave" FontSize="36"/>
    <Button x:Name="B" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="223,59,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Height="75" Click="button_click" Background="#FFEBEB33" MouseEnter="button_enter" MouseLeave="button_leave" FontSize="36"/>
    <Button x:Name="C" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="330,59,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Height="75" Click="button_click" Background="#FFEBEB33" MouseEnter="button_enter" MouseLeave="button_leave" FontSize="36"/>
    <Button x:Name="D" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="117,157,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Height="75" Click="button_click" Background="#FFEBEB33" MouseEnter="button_enter" MouseLeave="button_leave" FontSize="36"/>
    <Button x:Name="E" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="223,157,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Height="75" Click="button_click" Background="#FFEBEB33" MouseEnter="button_enter" MouseLeave="button_leave" FontSize="36"/>
    <Button x:Name="F" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="330,157,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Height="75" Click="button_click" Background="#FFEBEB33" MouseEnter="button_enter" MouseLeave="button_leave" FontSize="36"/>
    <Button x:Name="G" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="117,255,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Height="75" Click="button_click" Background="#FFEBEB33" MouseEnter="button_enter" MouseLeave="button_leave" FontSize="36"/>
    <Button x:Name="H" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="223,255,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Height="75" Click="button_click" Background="#FFEBEB33" MouseEnter="button_enter" MouseLeave="button_leave" FontSize="36"/>
    <Button x:Name="I" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="330,255,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Height="75" Click="button_click" Background="#FFEBEB33" MouseEnter="button_enter" MouseLeave="button_leave" FontSize="36"/>
    <ToolBar Margin="0,0,0,450.6">
        <Button Name="newButton" Click="newButton_Click">New</Button>
    </ToolBar>
    <Label Content="X Win Count" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="117,369,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold"/>
    <Label Content="Draw Count" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="233,369,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold"/>
    <Label Content="O Win Count" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="348,369,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold"/>
    <Label x:Name="x_win_count" Content="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="138,400,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Label x:Name="draw_count" Content="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="259,400,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Label x:Name="o_win_count" Content="{Binding Path=_o_win_counter, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="381,400,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 6):

Replace

```
Content="{Binding Path=_o_win_counter, ...}"
```

with

```
Content="{Binding Path=o_win_counter, ...}"
```

without the leading underline. The binding source must be the property, not the backing field. You may also rethink your property names. There is a widely accepted convention that property names in C# use CamelCasing.

Then you also have to specify the source object of the binding, which is the MainWindow instance in this case. There are a few ways to do this, but the perhaps simplest way here is to set the Window's DataContext property:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
}
```

You might want to read the [Data Binding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) article on MSDN.

Comment: @Sybren Sounds like your `DataContext` isn't setup correctly. If you're interested, I frequently direct new WPF users to my article [What is this "DataContext" you speak of?](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2012/07/14/what-is-this-datacontext-you-speak-of/). I find it often helps them understand the concept better than the MSDN page.

Comment: @Rachel helpful article way more understandable than the MSDN pages , thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should set your datacontext in constructor:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
}
```

You don't use MVVM so why don't you set it from code behind like:

```
o_win_count.Content= o_win_counter.ToString();
```

Comment: I added DataContext=this; and now it works, thanks. I should read into MVVM, just started WPF :).

Comment: Why set the DataContext, when you don't bind anything and instead set the content in code behind?

Comment: Not you @Clemens, said it to Sybren.

Comment: I gave an answer in a question that provided an alternate solution to a `groupby` which used an overloaded `groupby` and was marked down. Drive-by markdowns do no one any good.

Comment: Actually this is a little bit different. After I posted my answer, Clemens updated his answer with mine although Sybren accepted my answer. Sybren, you should mark as answer if any answer helps you.